# Java Swing Buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

So I have three buttons: add, edit and save. I am using ActionListener and getActionCommand to determine which button was pressed. 
If I press add, then save, it has to add a new person in my table. If I press edit, then save, it has to edit that person in the table. 
Is there any way to determine which button was pressed before save so that I know which way I go in Save button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Store which button was pressed in an instance variable in your class (I don't mean in your listener class).

Comment: So obvious I couldn't see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

by using getSource() we can do it

and add some conditions like flag=1 in add button, flag=2 in edit button

if flag=1 then add new record to a table

if flag=2 then edit existing record.

Answer (score 0):

A better way than using ActionListeners directly is to use Actions:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

I always felt like `getSource` was a big hack, don't know why you would ever need to use it.